# identify a sprite from ccarray cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ios6

I added three type of sprite in ccarray.

```
CCArray *storeObject=[[CCArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
    CCSprite *sprite1=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"sprite1.png"];
    CCSprite *sprite2=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"sprite2.png"];
    CCSprite *sprite3=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"sprite3.png"];
    [storeObject addObject:sprite1];
    [storeObject addObject:sprite2];
    [storeObject addObject:sprite3];
    [self addChild:sprite1 z:1 tag:100];
    [self addChild:sprite2 z:1 tag:101];
    [self addChild:sprite3 z:1 tag:102];
```

I am using this array a logic. where I want to identify these spites and want to perform different type of operations. then my question is that how can I identify these sprites from ccarray. please answer with syntax.
I added these three sprite randomly in array. Now in for loop I want to identify that which one sprite I have. how is this possible?

Comment: You can just relate the sprite tag with array index no??

Comment: @Anusha I know that But If I fill These sprites randomly and want to detect one of them.then how can I identify that which one sprite I have.

Comment: then you have to check each sprite tag in for loop to get matching sprite tag..

Comment: thanks for reply. I am using syntax something like this but I dont know its right or wrong. 
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
CCSprite *value=[storeObject objectAtIndex:i];
if([self getChildByTag:100] == value){
// some cde here.
}
}
is this right or not??

Comment: You can try my code below or change your code like : value.tag == 100. Also you have to cast [storeObject objectAtIndex:i] to CCSprite..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
for (CCSprite *spr in storeObject)
{
     if (spr.tag == currentTag)
     {
         // you will get the current sprite
         break;
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Its working. I use value.tag and its giving me a right answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, screw that extra CCArray (also: screw CCArray it's buggy, stick to NSMutableArray instead). You most likely don't need it at all. This simplifies your code into:

```
CCSprite *sprite1=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"sprite1.png"];
CCSprite *sprite2=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"sprite2.png"];
CCSprite *sprite3=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"sprite3.png"];
[self addChild:sprite1 z:1 tag:100];
[self addChild:sprite2 z:1 tag:101];
[self addChild:sprite3 z:1 tag:102];
```

Then to get the sprite with sprite3.png simply use getChildByTag:

```
CCSprite* itsSprite3 = [self getChildByTag:102];
```

After all that's what the tags are for!

If you only ever have 3 sprites and you don't remove them from its parten it's even easier if you just create 3 ivars sprite1, sprite2, sprite3 to access them any time anywhere in your class.

Comment: thanks for reply. actually I have three sprite and I wanted to store it in an array randomly at least with 10 capacity. Now    I wanted to fetch value from that array and wanted to identify that which one sprite I have.

Answer (score 0):

for completeness, you should be aware that you can add multiple children to an object that have the same tag. For example, the code below will provide the log after :

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    CCLabelAtlas *toto = [SpriteUtils mapDamageLabel:23+i];

    toto.tag = 901210;
    [self addChild:toto z:0 tag:toto.tag];;
}

MPLOG(@"*** remove me : before refresh %@ ***", self.soldier);
for (id child in children_) {
    CCNode *ch = (CCNode *) child;
    MPLOG(@"<%@> tag: %i name : %@", self.soldier, ch.tag, ch.name);
}
```

*** now the log ***

-[SoldierMapLayout sequenceEngagement:] : *** remove me : before refresh red ***

-[SoldierMapLayout sequenceEngagement:] :  tag: 1024 name : CCSprite : walk_red_rogue_idle0001.png

-[SoldierMapLayout sequenceEngagement:] :  tag: 891 name : CCSprite : cant move

-[SoldierMapLayout sequenceEngagement:] :  tag: 889 name : CCSprite : cant heal

-[SoldierMapLayout sequenceEngagement:] :  tag: 890 name : CCSprite : Charmed

-[SoldierMapLayout sequenceEngagement:] :  tag: 886 name : CCSprite : Health bar : 18

-[SoldierMapLayout sequenceEngagement:] :  tag: 896 name : CCSprite : walk_red_rogue_cast0001.png

-[SoldierMapLayout sequenceEngagement:] :  tag: 895 name : CCLabelAtlas : critical damage 16

-[SoldierMapLayout sequenceEngagement:] :  tag: 901210 name : CCLabelAtlas : damage 23

-[SoldierMapLayout sequenceEngagement:] :  tag: 901210 name : CCLabelAtlas : damage 24

-[SoldierMapLayout sequenceEngagement:] :  tag: 901210 name : CCLabelAtlas : damage 25

-[SoldierMapLayout sequenceEngagement:] :  tag: 901210 name : CCLabelAtlas : damage 26

-[SoldierMapLayout sequenceEngagement:] :  tag: 901210 name : CCLabelAtlas : damage 27

-[SoldierMapLayout sequenceEngagement:] :  tag: 901210 name : CCLabelAtlas : damage 28

-[SoldierMapLayout sequenceEngagement:] :  tag: 901210 name : CCLabelAtlas : damage 29

-[SoldierMapLayout sequenceEngagement:] :  tag: 901210 name : CCLabelAtlas : damage 30

-[SoldierMapLayout sequenceEngagement:] :  tag: 901210 name : CCLabelAtlas : damage 31

-[SoldierMapLayout sequenceEngagement:] :  tag: 901210 name : CCLabelAtlas : damage 32

therefore, when you later do a [self getChildByTag:901210], CCNode will return the first one it finds with the tag, not necessarily the one you are looking for.